# SUM, GROUP BY AND LEFT JOIN in query

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum, left-join

I've two tables:

```
`orders`
order_id    order_office_id     order_invoice_id  
1           1                   1
2           2                   2
3           2                   2
4           2                   3
5           1                   4

`invoices`
inv_id    inv_order_id  inv_amount  
1         1             500.00       
2         0             320.00
3         3             740.00
4         4             160.00
```

With this query:

```
SELECT SUM(inv_amount) matrah, order_office_id
FROM `invoices` 
LEFT JOIN orders ON order_invoice_id = inv_id OR inv_order_id = order_id
WHERE order_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY order_office_id
```

It is multiplying some amounts.

What I want to get sum of amounts by office:

```
office_id         sum
1              660.00
2             1060.00
```

How to get proper amounts by single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what you want, I think

```
select sum(inv_amount) as matrah,
(select order_office_id from orders where order_invoice_id = inv_id  limit 1) as office
from invoices
group by office;
```

I've removed the OR, because you were getting two office ids for one of the orders, so it was ambiguous. I've included a subquery to make sure that only one office is applied to each order.

Answer (score 0):

This query may help you out:

```
SELECT SUM(i.inv_amount) matrah, o.order_office_id
FROM `invoices` AS i
LEFT JOIN `orders` AS o 
ON o.order_invoice_id = i.inv_id
GROUP BY order_office_id
```

OR statement in your ON condition caused the problem.

Comment: The result is 1380.00 now for office no 2, expecting 1060.00. Adding an extra 320.00.

Comment: @baturalpdincdari OK, if you want inv_id to be distinct, just use LEFT JOIN.

Comment: The issue is that there are two lines in orders that have the same invoice id. However you join the tables, the value for that invoice (id 2) will get duplicated, unless you take steps to only fetch it once.